# Dynamic web design, a newbie

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good day,

I am just at the "dawn" of web design and I haven't been able to find a good answer to

this question as of now.

"Let us say I would like to create a website that has 3 pages:

1) Index\Home
2) Contact
3) Personal Works

In the personal works section I would like a list to appear which is ok, I would just go

```
<ul><li></li></ul> etc etc
```

Now Let us pretend that in the `<li></li>` I want to put names of poems I have written as per my personal website portfolio. Each li would then send you to the requested poem.
All is good. 
Now to the real question: I assume that creating 150+ html files for each single poem is a suicide, useless and dumb. That said, how do I actually do it?

I don't need you to do hard-coding for me. If you could just explain a little bit and maybe post a few tutorials\examples, Id be glad.

Love you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is where a server-side language is used. You use the server-side language to read some parameters and then provide the solution depending on the condition.

I would recommend you to use ASP.NET, or you can use PHP or some other server-side languages. But my preference is ASP.NET.

### Solution:

You can try something like, one single page named: `poem.cshtml` (cshtml is a file, which accepts C# code alongwith HTML). Then inside the page you show the code depending on the URL. Lets say you're having a simple poem of **Twinkle Twinkle Little Star**. Then

```
http://www.example.com/poem/twinkle-twinkle-little-star
```

Now you can get the poem name using:

```
var poemName = UrlData[0];
```

Then use an `if else` block to do this:

```
if(poemName == "twinkle-twinkle-little-star") {
  /* write that poem
   * or by using else block, show other poems */
}
```

This is easy to understand and learn.

You can use Database to save the Poem and show it using ASP.NET. You need to learn alot.

#### Start Learning

http://basicsofwebdevelopment.wordpress.com (Beginner's Site)

http://developer.mozilla.org (To learn HTML, CSS)

http://www.asp.net (Official ASP.NET website)

Comment: Those languages differences are about syntax only or one also has more "power" than the other?

Comment: No, there is nothing that is known as Power in programming language. It is just the shortness or length of the syntax. For example in ASP.NET to connect you just write `Database.Open("dbName");` whereas in other language, it is a hell lot of coding lines...that's why I prefer ASP.NET :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need depends on how all that would be used. You may really need to use server-side language, or if content is generated on client side, respective array of li would be generated using javascript

Answer (score 0):

For a newbie PHP would be the easiest server side language to learn, mixed with javascript, ASP.NET is also a nice language but a bit more of a learning curve although if you have any C# experience learning it would be easier.